# Android Media Player - 903 warning

Tags: android, media-player

I have a problem with video not been playing. I am using `SurfaceView` with `MediaPlayer`.

Those are my actions:

1. MediaPlayer.setDataSource(url)
2. MediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
3. MediaPlayer.start() // From setOnPreparedListener listener
4. MediaPlayer.reset()
5. Go back to 1 with different url

About 3 out of 5 videos do not start playing. I see nothing in the logs except some times when video does start it show me this:

> W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (1, 903)

Can't find 903 in the [documentations](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h).